# What is the best R implementation of Jaccard index to compute similarity of Wikipedia articles from their titles?

Tags: r, performance, time, similarity, wikipedia-api

Suppose I have a list of titles of Wikipedia articles and I would like to measure similarity between the articles.

```
title <- c("virus", 
  "coronavirus",
  "Coronaviridae",
  "pandemic", 
  "2019–20_coronavirus_pandemic", 
  "Coronavirus_disease_2019",
  "Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome_coronavirus_2",
  "Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome_coronavirus",
  "Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome-related_coronavirus",
  "syndrome",
  "disease",
  "infection"
  )
```

Here are some solutions, but I presume that they are not the quickest ways to do this task for long lists of titles. Furthermore, results are not exactly the same.

First, a function to get Wikipedia article:

```
GetArticle <- function(pageName){
  library(xml2)
  library(httr)
  query <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?", 
                  "action=query", "&format=xml", "&redirects", "&prop=extracts",
                  "&explaintext","&titles=", pageName)
  answer <- httr::GET(query)
  page.xml <- xml2::read_xml(answer)
  page <- xml2::xml_find_all(page.xml, "//extract")
  text <- as.character(base::trimws(xml_text(page)))
}
article <- unlist(lapply(title, GetArticle))
```

I tested these possible solutions. A first "basic" implementation.

```
function1 <- function(article){
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  cleanArticle <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", article)
  cleanArticle <- gsub("[0-9]", "", cleanArticle)
  titles.df <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(title, title))
  names(titles.df) <- c("title1", "title2")
  couples <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(cleanArticle,cleanArticle))

  similarity <- function(text1, text2){
    tokens1 <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(text1, " ")))
    tokens2 <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(text2, " ")))
    intersection.v <- sort(intersect(tokens1, tokens2))
    union.v <- sort(union(tokens1, tokens2))
    cardinalityOfIntersection <- length(intersection.v)
    cardinalityOfUnion <- length(union.v)
    score <- cardinalityOfIntersection / cardinalityOfUnion
    return(score)
  }

  score <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(article)) {
    jaccardIndex <- similarity(as.character(couples$Var1[i]), 
                               as.character(couples$Var2[i]))
    score <- c(score, jaccardIndex)
  }

  results.df <- cbind(titles.df, score)
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  time <- end_time - start_time
  print(time)
  return(results.df)
}
```

A second solution built from quanteda package:

```
function2 <- function(article){
  # https://quanteda.io/reference/textstat_simil.html
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  library(quanteda)
  dfma <- dfm(article)

  scores <- textstat_simil(dfma, method = "jaccard", margin = "documents")
  mat <- as.matrix(scores)
  rownames(mat) <- title
  colnames(mat) <- title
  library(reshape2)
  candidates <- as.data.frame(subset(melt(mat), value!=0))
  names(candidates) <- c("title1", "title2", "score")
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  time <- end_time - start_time
  print(time)
  return(candidates)
}
```

A third solution built from reuse package:

```
function3 <- function(article){
  # https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textreuse/vignettes/textreuse-pairwise.html
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  library(textreuse)
  corpus <- TextReuseCorpus(text=article, tokenizer = tokenize_words, progress = FALSE)
  names(corpus) <- title
  comparisons <- pairwise_compare(corpus, jaccard_similarity)

  comparisons.df <- as.data.frame(comparisons)

  candidates <- pairwise_candidates(comparisons)
  names(candidates) <- c("title1", "title2", "score")
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  time <- end_time - start_time
  print(time)
  return(candidates)
}
```

Solutions can be compared:

```
results1.df <- function1(article)
results2.df <- function2(article)
results3.df <- function3(article)

system.time(function1(article))
system.time(function2(article))
system.time(function3(article))

View(results1.df)
View(results2.df)
View(results3.df)
```

Some indications:

```
> results1.df <- function1(article)
Time difference of 1.176277 secs
> results2.df <- function2(article)
Time difference of 0.3198049 secs
> results3.df <- function3(article)
Making 66 comparisons.
  |============================================================================================================================| 100%
Time difference of 0.2578409 secs


> system.time(function1(article))
Time difference of 1.100325 secs
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       1.08        0.00        1.09 
> system.time(function2(article))
Time difference of 0.402745 secs
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.45        0.00        0.41 
> system.time(function3(article))
Making 66 comparisons.
  |============================================================================================================================| 100%
Time difference of 0.1998792 secs
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.22        0.00        0.22
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: How is "best" defined? That's a very subjective adjective. What exactly are your requirements? What problems so you have with the above solutions.